# Finding total cost of road

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns `source`, `dest`, `total cost` and have values like

```
Agra Delhi 500
Agra Kanpur 400
Delhi Agra 900
Kanpur Agra 500
```

I want total cost like

```
Agra<-->Delhi 1400
Agra<-->Kanpur 900
```

Comment: What did you mean with `<-->`

Comment: Actually  i want total cost of trips of each route i.e to and fro

Comment: It seems, `Agra<-->Delhi 1400` he wanted the total distance of to and fro i.e Agra to Delhi & Delhi to Agra i.e. 500 + 900 = 1400.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LEAST() and GREATEST() functions, and a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT
  LEAST(source, dest),
  GREATEST(source, dest),
  SUM(total_cost)
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  LEAST(source, dest),
  GREATEST(source, dest)
```

Comment: are these oracle functions, LEAST() GREATEST()?? impressed!! never used one!! +1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.source, a.dest, (a.total_cost + b.total_cost) round_trip_cost
FROM my_tab as a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN my_tab as b 
    ON (a.source = b.dest AND b.source = a.dest)
```

Comment: This would return double rows.